# How do I change my $OutputPath in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm getting an error in VS2010 that the HasTrailingSlash function only accepts a scalar value, but the argument $(OutputPath) evaluates to something that isn't a scalar.

Trouble is, I can't find the $(OutputPath) variable anywhere. I have no idea what it is, or how to go in and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me the fix was to edit my Computers Environment Variables, specifically the TEMP variable which had more than one entry. I left one entry which is:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;
```

If there is an entry close to that in your variable I would recommend leaving that one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project(s) properties area under the build tab.

Look for the output area on that tab and the OutputPath textbox.

If no luck there:

Check your project file(s) by unloading them and clicking edit project file. Look for an outputPath defined there. I believe that exists by default in Vs2010.

If none of that helps, tell us if this is a build attempted inside the Vs2010 or a seperate command line or build script.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

**Option 1**

- Right click on the project, to bring out the Properties window
- View/edit the output path (you can even browse to a directory)

[image: Project window]

Option 2

- Open the project file (*.csproj) in your favorite text editor, and search for the  tag

[image: Project file]

A note of caution with the second option. There could be multiple entries that match the tag. So make sure you're changing the Configuration/Platform combination you mean to modify.